# В какую папку нужно положить проект git?

Tags: symfony, git, php, ubuntu

Поставил Git, использую ОС Ubuntu Server. Потом поставил LAMP сервер, все последней версии. Затем поставил GitList (web интерфейс для Git). Все делал по офф. инструкции, но получил такие 6 ошибок:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There
>   are no GIT repositories in /home/vallverk/.git/' in
>   /var/www/src/GitList/Git/Client.php:41 Stack trace: #0
>
> /var/www/src/GitList/Util/Routing.php(115):
>   GitList\Git\Client->getRepositories(Array) #1
>
> /var/www/src/GitList/Controller/MainController.php(48):
>   GitList\Util\Routing->getRepositoryRegex() #2
>
> /var/www/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php(456):
>   GitList\Controller\MainController->connect(Object(GitList\Application)) #3
>
> /var/www/boot.php(7): Silex\Application->mount('',
>   Object(GitList\Controller\MainController)) #4
>
> /var/www/index.php(29): require('/var/www/boot.p...') #5 {main} thrown
>   in /var/www/src/GitList/Git/Client.php on line 41

Первый вопрос в какую папку GIT (branches, hooks, info или objects, или в другую?) нужно положить проект? Что можете прокомментировать по другим ошибкам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There are no GIT repositories in /home/vallverk/.git/' in /var/www/src/GitList/Git/Client.php:41 Stack trace: #0

Директория `.git` сама по себе не является репозиторием. Репозиторием называется директория проекта с лежащей в ней директорией `.git`. Соответственно, в вашем случае репозиторием будет считаться директория `/home/vallverk`.

---

Если это продолжение разговора о git-сервере, то в таком случае под проекты создаются так называемые bare-репозитории, т.е. репозитории не имеющие рабочей директории (да и зачем она там, работа с над исходным кодом проекта ведь не будет вестись на сервере)

Все взаимодействие с репозиторием в таком случае должно производиться через pull/push.

> Что можете прокомментировать по другим ошибкам?

Текст ошибки тут в первой строчке, все остальное - трассировка.